# clickTAG - so simple - but not working

Tags: flash, embed, clicktag

Ok - this is driving me insane!! A client of mine requested a quick clickTAG added to a banner using the legacy solution shared by Adobe themselves.

http://www.adobe.com/resources/richmedia/tracking/designers_guide/

Easy enough. I applied the AS to the button symbol:

```
on (release) {
if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {
getURL(clickTAG);
}
}
```

then did a simple EMBED src to test it:

```
<EMBED src="ad_banner_example.swf?clickTAG=http://www.destinationURL.com">
```

and... nothing. I performed a trace to make sure the button symbol works - all good there. Again this is driving me nuts.

published:

Player 7
AS 2.0

---

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

checking if clickTags work correctly can only be done through an ad-serving platform. Each ad server uses a specific format of the clickTag code so the only real way to ensure your code is correct is for the banner to be trafficked and tested through the ad server they are using.
The most you can do from Flash itself is to run a trace to make sure the clickTag button is firing, i'm afraid